# After update trigger not working, don't know how to set proper conditions

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I'm trying to create a `trigger` for my hospital database. It's a simple project, so the `assumption` is that if a patient is checked out of the hospital, He is completely cured. So the `trigger` has to delete a record from `patient_diseases` `(it contains id, patient_id, disease_id)` table when a `check_out_date` column in `visit` `(visit contains id, check_in_date, check_out_date and patient_id)` table is changed from null to an actual date.

```
    USE hospital;

    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS cure_patient;
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER cure_patient
    AFTER UPDATE ON visit
    FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        IF NEW.check_out_date != NULL THEN
             DELETE from patient_disease WHERE ???
        END IF;
        END;
    //
    DELIMITER ;
```

So far I came up with this, I just don't what I should write to make the script take `patient_id` from visit in which the date was changed and delete the record with the same `patient_id` from a different table.

```
    visit | CREATE TABLE `visit` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `check_in_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `check_out_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `patient_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `patient_id2` (`patient_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `patient_id2` FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES 'patient` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

    | p_d  | CREATE TABLE `p_d` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `patient_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `disease_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `patient_id_idx` (`patient_id`),
      KEY `disease_id_idx` (`disease_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `disease_id` FOREIGN KEY (`disease_id`) REFERENCES `choroba` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `patient_id` FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES `patient` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: `DELETE from patient_disease pd WHERE pd.patient_id = new.patient_id`?

Comment: That didn't work, it says:  Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'patient_id' in 'NEW'.

Comment: Well.. Post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE visit` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE patient_disease`.

Comment: Please use the edit button and post the code in the question - Not in a comment!

Comment: I can't reproduce the "Unknown column" error. The trigger is accepted on rexester: http://rextester.com/GDEC25703

Comment: The problem is here: `IF NEW.check_out_date != NULL THEN`. Replace `!= NULL` with `is not NULL`

Comment: @matino That is correct. But `!= NULL` should not produce an error.

Comment: Ok, solved it, @PaulSpiegel suggestion was correct, I just had DELETE from p_d, whereas it should be DELETE p_d from p_d. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The trigger body should be:

```
BEGIN
    IF NEW.check_out_date IS NOT NULL THEN
         DELETE p_d FROM p_d WHERE p_d.patient_id = new.patient_id;
    END IF;
END
```

Note that `NEW.check_out_date != NULL` would never be `TRUE` since any comparison with `NULL` (except of `<=>`) will always return `NULL`. So you need to use `IS NOT NULL` instead.

This trigger can also be written with a single statement (in this case you don't need to use `BEGIN` and `END` and change the delimiter):

```
CREATE TRIGGER cure_patient
    AFTER UPDATE ON visit
    FOR EACH ROW
        DELETE p_d FROM p_d
        WHERE NEW.check_out_date IS NOT NULL
          AND p_d.patient_id = new.patient_id;
```